# cannot connect to the mongo database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I cann't connect to the database mongo db. The type error is present. How can I do?
server.js:

```
let MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
let express = require("express");
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");
let app = express();
let db;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("Hello API");
});

app.listen(3114, function() {
  console.log("API app started");
});
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test_db", {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
```

Console log:

```
API app started
TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
at /home/bukrole/db.project/server.js:18:6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `mongodb://localhost:27017/` in your connection string to resolve that error. However, you need to mention the db name separately as an option.

```
var db;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
    db = client.db('test_db');
});
```

Comment: (node:5188) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

Comment: @Александр that should have worked, Please check properly.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I add { useUnifiedTopology: true } parameter and warning is missing. Thanks for your answer